# What is the difference (if any) between "yield" and "yield return" in C#?

Tags: c#, yield, yield-return

I've traditionally used yield in C# without the return, e.g.:

```
IEnumerable<T> Foobar() {
   foreach( var foo in _stuff ) {
      yield foo;
   }
}
```

But in other examples I've seen it written as "yield return foo;", see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28VS.80%29.aspx.

Is there any difference?

Comment: I wasn't aware that 'yield' by itself like that would even compile. The keyword is 'yield return'.

Comment: Try reading the reference first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# does not allow `yield` all by itself - only `yield return` and `yield break`.

`yield` is a contextual keyword that is only recognized inside iterator blocks and only in conjunction with either `return` or `break`.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I remembered being able to write yield without return. Too long away from C# I guess.

Comment: In the original design of iterator blocks it was just yield without the return, but I don't believe any of those versions ever actually shipped to the public. The design team realized that if they made it yield return then they would not have to make a new reserved keyword.